# How can I make a Wordpress query which only uses some of the tags associated with the post and not all the tags?

Tags: tags, wordpress

I am trying to display related content on my website using tags.
My posts have multiple tags that link to similar content.

When running the query on a post I would like to ignore certain tags.
Is this possible?

e.g.

Post-A has 3 tags, Tag-1, Tag-2 and Tag-3

Post-B has 5 tags, Tag-1, Tag-2, Tag-4, Tag-5 and Tag-6

For my query I require Tag-1 and Tag-2 to always be ignored.

My Ideal result would be;

Post-A displays Tag-3 and Post-B displays Tag-4, Tag-5 and Tag-6

Answer (score 1):

```
use this wp query . I hope it will work for you. 

$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 10 ) ) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

endwhile;
```